# undefined method `user_sessions_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0xdb3158>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error that's driving me up the wall. I don't see what's going on... I've followed instructions to the T and it's still complaining - help please!! I've got extracts of the error message, controller file, login page and routes file.

## Error message

```rb
NoMethodError in User_sessions#new
Showing app/views/user_sessions/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:
undefined method `user_sessions_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1fe766f>
```

Extracted source (around line #4):

## app/views/user/login.rhtml

```rb
4. <% form_for @user_session do |f| %>
5.  <%= f.error_messages %>
```

## controller/user_sessions_controller.rb

```rb
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_user, :only => :destroy

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
      redirect_to root_url
      #redirect_back_or_default account_url
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Logout successful!"
    redirect_to root_url
    #redirect_back_or_default account_url
  end
end
```

## user_sessions/new.html.erb

```rb
#User Login

<% form_for @user_session do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

## routes.rb file

```rb
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.login "login", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "new"
```

Am I look in in the wrong place??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your routes file. You're not doing sessions restfully. So the `<%form_for @user_session%>` won't know how to create a url.

Adding `map.resource: user_session` to routes.rb should fix your problem.

You should read through the [restful_authentication plugin's  documentation.](http://wiki.github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in formtastic to me.
I'm getting the same error with the route map.resource :user_session.

Formtastic should be posting to the singular route name, not the plural since user_session is a singular resource.